# Stuck in simulation in LTspice. ESD generator

Tags: ltspice, esd

I am trying to simulate an ESD generator equivalent circuit.

My schematic is attached below.

I am not getting any voltage. I am guessing there is something I am missing, but I cannot think of what it might be.

[image]

I am expecting an output as following:

[image]

Comment: you cannot specify the initial voltage across components with .ic as you are seemingly attempting. Instead that command specifies the initial voltage of a node/net. you define nets 'c1' and 'c2' which don't exist. change the command to '.ic V(ESD)=4k'

Answer (score 5):

Add label "C1" AND "c2" on wires connecting capacitors C1  and C2 to the resistors R1 and R2, this will permit the Initial conditions .IC to work as desired.
Best regards
Enrique B

Comment: This should be the answer (given OP's picture).

Answer (score 3):

You need to put some kind of load on the \$V_{ESD}\$. As it is, there is no return path for C1 and C2 to discharge through.

Comment: 1 ohm resistor from the ESD port to ground will give the current waveform in the expected graph.

Comment: There's no need to add a load in this case, it's not DC.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen if they expect a discharge output, then they need to add a DUT/discharge path.

Comment: @tobalt You're right, I discounted that part (though it still doesn't answer OP's problem).

Answer (score 2):

You also need to add initial conditions for L1 and L2:
.IC V(C1)=ESD_Voltage V(C2)=ESD_Voltage I(L1)=0 I(L2)=0
.param ESD_Voltage=4k (or what ever voltage you want to test)

Comment: While it could be done this way, OP's problem relates to missing node labels for which the `.ic` conditions are made, and that's [Enrique Batikoff's anwer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/239626/95619). Which means there's no "need" to add those initial conditions for the inductors.